# Regexp. How to extract values from xml document

Tags: java, xml, regex

I just started to figure out what regexp is, but I have really limited time!

I have a string in xml like : `<myid>1234</myid>`, for now my xml is in txt it used to be an xml document.

How can I make pattern to extract 1234 from `<myid>` tag.

Comment: Don't, and use an XML parser instead. An XPath expression will probably be easy to write for your use case.

Comment: I would use XPath to get the value. Using regexp to get values from xml content isn't that pretty.

Comment: I have malformed xml document. I can't parse it because I have & sign and this & sign should stay same.

Comment: @user3108395: Clearly it *shouldn't* stay the same, it's creating an invalid XML document. To fix it: `str = str.replaceAll("\\&([^a-zA-Z0-9])", "&amp;$1");` or similar.

Comment: But it have to. Because programm where I send my xml doc. doesn't not exept it with no & sign!

Comment: If the program where you send it needs this, then that program also needs to be fixed.

Comment: This programm where I send this xml change it inside. Just please give me pattern how to extract number between tag, the other things I will figure out by myself.

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal effort in solving the actual problem, including the attempted code and the encountered issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it *really* looks like this:

```
<myid>1234</myid>
```

...you can extract it like this:

```
Matcher match = Pattern.compile("<myid>(\d+)</myid>").matcher(str);
```

...and then use the matcher repeatedly, getting the value from the capture group.

But ***there's a reason*** everyone is telling you to use a proper parser. There are lots of ways the above can fail, both matching inappropriately and failing to match when it should.

The proper solution is to make the XML valid, and then parse it, and use XPath or similar to read the values.

If you really have some tool requiring you to send it invalid XML, you need to replace that tool. More likely, though, it's some misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you T.J. Crowder. I understand but this how it works.